# PHP MySQL calculation AS not working

Tags: php, mysql

I tried searching for a similar case here in SO but I can't find the right search result. My problem is this:

I have this query which works fine and displays a lot of results (`net_salary` is the result of subtraction between `salary` and `totaldeductions` fields which are both stored as float. I can't remember why but I needed to store them as float):

`SELECT name, address, city, state, zip_code, salary-totaldeductions as net_salary FROM employees WHERE state = 'CA' ORDER BY address ASC`

If I try to modify it and add `AND net_salary > 5000` the page/frame becomes blank:

`SELECT name, address, city, state, zip_code, salary-totaldeductions as net_salary FROM employees WHERE state = 'CA' AND net_salary > 5000 ORDER BY address ASC`

I tried searching where the code fails, it seems `if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $MyQuery))` fails. The first query works and `net_salary`works but on the second query where I tried using the variable `net_salary` in a condition it fails, is it wrong to use the variable that was created in a query as a condition in a query? Can you spot what was wrong?

Comment: Try ---> AND (salary - totaldeductions) > 5000

Comment: The where clause evaluates the condition first and at that time, the AS net_salary is an unknown. Try the one suggested by @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob

Comment: type decimal (instead of float) would have worked also since monetary values will always have precisely 2 numerals after decimal point

Comment: Thanks guys, so I guess the summarized answer is you can't use an alias in a WHERE? I had to use alias so I can sort the columns of the table (Some columns aren't columns in MySQL Database but were created after some calculations between existing columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the result try below query :

```
SELECT name, address, city, state, zip_code, (salary - totaldeductions) as net_salary FROM employees WHERE state = 'CA' AND (salary - totaldeductions) > 5000 ORDER BY address ASC
```

Here you need to put same condition in where conditions. If you want to use alias into where than it will not work but Having is used but Having is used with aggregate column.

Try this query.

Comment: I used `salary - totaldeductions as net_salary` with no clause as there's only 1 step of calculation there though, but this made it clear for me that my mistake was using Alias in a WHERE statement in MySQL Query

Answer (score 0):

Because `net_salary` is an alias I think you need to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`:

```
SELECT name, address, city, state, zip_code, salary-totaldeductions as net_salary FROM employees WHERE state = 'CA' HAVING net_salary > 5000 ORDER BY address ASC
```

In future, if a SQL call fails, you can look at  `$stmt->error` to see what went wrong.

Comment: HAVING refers to GROUP BY  or aggregates not aliases

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob Actualy -> "`MySQL extends this behavior to permit the use of an alias in the HAVING clause for the aggregated column`" . You are correct about most RDBMS, but not MySQL .

Comment: `HAVING` can also refer to aliases.

Comment: Just to sharpen this statement - Only in MySQL @BenHillier

Comment: @sagi I believe you. The problem is that I've used MySQL and MariaDB exclusively since 2001. I don't know what's standard and whats implementation specific anymore ;-)